# How to merge video (with audio) and audio files of different length but follow the audio files length

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to merge an mp4 (with video and audio) with an mp3 to make a final mp4. The inputs can be of different lengths but the output should follow the mp3/audio file.

So if the mp3 is shorter than the video then the video is cut short.

And if the mp3 is longer than the video - last frame of the mp4 is replicated until the audio ends.

I also want to adjust the volume of the audio in the input mp4 based by some factor that is determined separately.

I've seen posts like this one [merging video and audio with different durations](https://superuser.com/questions/812395/merging-video-and-audio-with-different-durations) and the secret seems to lie in the -filter_complex command but I haven't found a good source that explains how to use that cl switch.

I've looked at FFmpeg.org but filter_complex is scattered through the docs. Its like you have to know most of it because you can piece it together.

Does anyone have a good "-filter_complex for dummies" doc or do you know what FFmpeg command I should use to accomplish my goal?

fwiw - I did run the command in the post I linked and expectedly got this error.

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [1:a]volume=0.15,apad[A];[0:a][A]amerge[out] matches no streams.
```

Answer (score 2):

So I was never able to find a "filter_Complex" for dummies but I pieced things together.

The answer is as follows.

merge where recorded audio is longer than video

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -i rec15.webm  -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.2,apad[A];[1:a][A]amerge[Aout]" -map 0:v -map [Aout] -y output-final.mp4
```

merge where recorded audio is shorter than video

```
ffmpeg -i vidlong.mov -i rec15.webm  -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.2[A];[1:a][A]amerge[Aout]" -map 0:v -map [Aout] -y -shortest output-final2.mp4
```

To understand at least the first part

```
[0:a]volume=0.2,apad[A]
```

is a filter chain combining volume change and padding audio.

- [0:a] is the "a"audio stream of the 0 input. in this case vid.mp4.
- volume=0.2 is a filter called volume where its first parameter is % of current where 0.2 is 20% of is current volume.
- after volume is finished the next action is to apad (audio pad)which will fill the remaining time with nothing.
- [A] takes the result of these changes.

This represents a filter with the input [0:a], the action - volume change, pad the audio with nothing, and the output to essentially variable [A].

Now a separate filter is to amerge which is audio merge.

```
[1:a][A]amerge[Aout]
```

- [1:a]represents the inputs with [1:a] being the 1 input and a being its audio. In this case its the mp3 file.
- [A] represents the output 'variable' from the last filter chain. amerge requires two inputs so both are provided. 
  [Aout] is the output from this merge. We could call it whatever btw.  These variables dont have to be A or Aout.

That is it for the filters

Now map basically translates to what will show up in the output file. Each map represents a stream in the output file and they are laid down in order so the first -map will represent stream 0 and so on.

```
-map 0:v
```

This means - the first stream is is the video 'v' of the 0 input.  I could also refer to the video stream by its number. In my case it would be 0:1 but you can use v to do the same thing.

```
-map [Aout]
```

This now represents the next stream in the output file which will be the audio stream. We reference the output from the filter with its final 'variable' [Aout].

the -y just tells FFmpeg to overwrite the target file without having to prompt.

and thats it.

I am in no way an expert and im sure there are nuances that I am missing here but this is what I was able to figure out and it meets my needs.